# Django VirtualEnv Setup - 'setuptools pip wheel failed with error code -11'

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm following a setup tutorial for Django where I have to set up a virtual environment in my folder. I didn't have `virtualenv`, so I did `sudo pip install virtualenv` and got this message after it was installed:

```
Chriss-MacBook-Air:trydjango18 cnowak7$ sudo pip install virtualenv
The directory '/Users/cnowak7/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/cnowak7/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-13.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.7MB 120kB/s 
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-13.1.0
```

After this, I tried creating a virtual environment like in the tutorial with `virtualenv .` and got this abnormal output:

```
Chriss-MacBook-Air:trydjango18 cnowak7$ virtualenv .
Using base prefix '/Users/cnowak7/anaconda'
New python executable in ./bin/python3
Also creating executable in ./bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cnowak7/anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/cnowak7/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/cnowak7/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1004, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Users/cnowak7/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 969, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Users/cnowak7/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 910, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/cnowak7/Deskt...django18/bin/python3 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code -11
```

So I tried to see if this error would affect my progress in the tutorial, so when I ran `source bin/activate`, I got this error:

```
Chriss-MacBook-Air:trydjango18 cnowak7$ source bin/activate
-bash: bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling `pip` and `virtualenv`, but this problem persists. Is this possibly because I have every in my Anaconda folder directory? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try this: `pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade`

Comment: I tried this with no luck. This is the error I get:

Comment: Chriss-MacBook-Air:~ cnowak7$ pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cnowak7/anaconda/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by going to www.brew.sh and running the following command in my Terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

From my understanding, it basically gave me all the packages and libraries that I was missing that Apple didn't originally give me. I hope this helps for anyone else who was experiencing this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

and then:

```
virtualenv your_virtualenv
```

Comment: If I'm installing pip and virtualenv again should I uninstall them first?

Comment: I'm getting `sudo: apt-get: command not found`. I looked it up and people are saying that Mac-OSX doesn't have that command apparently.

Comment: @Rafi updated the answer. you dont need to uninstall I think. try the updated answer

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cnowak7/anaconda/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

Comment: The easy install pip is working from this error happens after `sudo pip install virtualenv`.

Comment: ok then you dont need the second line, just do after `easy_install pip` this one: `virtualenv your_virtualenv`

Comment: This isn't working, and I keep getting the same error. Most likely because I'm missing the 'pkg-resources' module, thanks for trying to help, but would you like to carry this out in chat if you have the time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82114/discussion-between-doniyor-and-rafi).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as @Rafi. Upon examining error messages after executing

```
virtualenv .
```

, I got a clue from this error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
```

Did some search and found out it means bad interactions between virtualenv and Anaconda at [this link](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/618). This simple solution solved my problem:

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
conda install virtualenv
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer try to describe your answer... in your case, include some links to wherever you find that solution.